# How to not show the first image when you open the gallery - Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I using Fancybox 2 to create a image gallery with the examples from their website: [http://fancyapps.com/fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

I'm hiding all of the images except the first using using "display: none;"

HTML

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<div class="hidden">
   <a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
   <a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0
    });
```

Once you click to open the gallery I want to hide the first image so that the gallery opens up to the second image. How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `Skipping the first image` mean that the gallery should open from second image but first image is still part of the gallery? (if looping through the gallery first image would show at the end)

Comment: No actually I dont want the first image to show up at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the first image is not going to be included in the fancybox gallery, then it doesn't need to have the `fancybox` class since it will be used to fire the fancybox gallery only.

You could use a different class (e.g. `fancyboxLauncher`)

```
<a class="fancyboxLauncher" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" title="one"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

... and bind a `click` event to it like :

```
$(".fancyboxLauncher").on("click", function(){
    $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger("click");
    return false;
});
```

... **notice** that we used the method `.eq(0)` to fire the gallery from the first item, otherwise it will start from the last. Also notice that `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

You still need this code for the fancybox gallery

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
    padding: 0
});
```

Additionally, if the images for the fancybox gallery will be *hidden*, they actually don't need to have a thumbnail (`img` tag) otherwise you will be just adding an unnecessary overhead to your page load so you could do

```
<div class="hidden">
   <a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"></a>
   <a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q8bn6/)**

Comment: And if I have more then 1 gallery?

Comment: @John : you target the proper selector (*class*) of that gallery

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for an alternate answer, you could do something like:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="images/second-image.jpg">
  <img src="images/first-image.jpg" />
</a>
<!-- clicking on the above image will open second-image.jpg in the fancybox,
     though first-image.jpg is shown as the thumbnail. -->
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="images/third-image.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="images/fourth-image.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="images/and-so-on.jpg"></a>
```

This way you don't need to write extra CSS (to hide) nor jquery (to trigger)