# How to remove first image on fancybox gallery for weebly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, weebly

I've tried the samples given on stackflow > [How to not show the first image when you open the gallery - Fancybox 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266280/how-to-not-show-the-first-image-when-you-open-the-gallery-fancybox-2)

but, it doesn't work for mine.

By default, weebly has cloudZoom and fancybox. So in my product page, I'm trying to keep cloudZoom and add a fancybox option so users can zoom the image in pop up way. Hence i created another **href**. The whole fancybox and cloudzoom is working but I'm unable to remove the duplicated image in the gallery.

This is what i have on product image page.

```
<div id="wsite-com-product-images">
{{#main_image}}
<a href="{{full_url}}" class="w-fancybox" rel="lightbox[1]">zoom</a>
<a href="{{full_url}}" class="cloud-zoom" id="zoom1" data-position="inside">
<img src="{{normal_url}}" class="wsite-com-product-images-main-image" itemprop="image"/></a>
{{/main_image}}

{{#has_other_images}}
<div id="wsite-com-product-images-strip" class="wsite-com-column-group">
{{#images}}
<a id="wsite-com-product-images-secondary-{{id}}" href="{{full_url}}" class="w-fancybox wsite-com-product-images-secondary wsite-com-column cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="lightbox[1]" data-zoom-id="zoom1" data-small-image="{{thumbnail_url}}">
<div class="wsite-com-product-images-secondary-outer">
{{{thumbnail_html}}}
</div>
</a>
{{/images}}
</div>
{{/has_other_images}}
</div>

// Side Swiping Galleries
swipeGallery: function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var touchGallery = document.getElementsByClassName("fancybox-wrap")[0];
    var mc = new Hammer(touchGallery);
    mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
      if (ev.type == "panleft") {
        $("a.fancybox-next").trigger("click");
      }
      else if (ev.type == "panright") {
        $("a.fancybox-prev").trigger("click");
      }
      Brisk.swipeGallery();
    });
  }, 500);
},
swipeInit: function(){
  if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    $("body").on( "click", "a.w-fancybox", function(){
      Brisk.swipeGallery();
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: If you have tried samples from that post, can you clarify "it doesn't work for mine"?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! So when I tried the code from the other post, the "zoom link" can be click but it only open into a new tab instead of fancy box. It also doesn't link up with the other images. The only connection for my fancy box to link is the rel=lightbox[1]. But I'm suppose to not have that on the main image right? So that they don't get duplicated? ):

Comment: i added my jquery from weebly itself, maybe you could see if smth is wrong?