# How to not always start with first photo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I got a image gallery preview of 5 thumbnails, but the gallery has even more photos. To avoid putting all  to my code and hide them via CSS, I am looking for another solution.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="start_slides2">
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb4.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb5.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

No problem so far. I could use the common way or put it to an object like this:

```
$("#start_slides2 a").on('click', function () {
    $.fancybox.open([
    { src: 'photo1.jpg', opts: { caption: 'First caption' } },
    { src: 'photo2.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Second caption' } },
    { src: 'photo3.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Third caption' } },
    { src: 'photo4.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Fourth caption' } },
    { src: 'photo5.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Fifth caption' } },
    { src: 'photo6.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Sixth caption' } },
    { src: 'photo7.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Seventh caption' } },
    { src: 'photo8.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Eigth caption' } }],
    { loop: true }
    );
});
```

The problem is that it always starts with the first item, even if a user clicked on the third thumbnail e.g.

How can I show the clicked image but also keep the chance to show up to x photos?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to not show the first image when you open the gallery - Fancybox 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266280/how-to-not-show-the-first-image-when-you-open-the-gallery-fancybox-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to pass `index` as 3rd parameter (see docs https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api), for example:

```
var $links = $("#start_slides2 a");

$links.on('click', function () {
    $.fancybox.open([
    { src: 'photo1.jpg', opts: { caption: 'First caption' } },
    { src: 'photo2.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Second caption' } },
    { src: 'photo3.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Third caption' } },
    { src: 'photo4.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Fourth caption' } },
    { src: 'photo5.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Fifth caption' } },
    { src: 'photo6.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Sixth caption' } },
    { src: 'photo7.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Seventh caption' } },
    { src: 'photo8.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Eigth caption' } }],
    { loop: true }, $links.index(this)
    );
});
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/cfnaw4oL/